# Go: Why are structs "instantiated" differently from other types?

Tags: go

In golang, structs are instantiated differently from "regular" types:

If it's a regular type: `MyFloat(2)`

If it's a struct: `MyFloat{2}`

Is there a particular reason for this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyFloat float64

type MyFloat2 struct {
    X float64
}

func main() {
    f1 := MyFloat(2)
    f2 := MyFloat2{3}
    fmt.Println(f1)
    fmt.Println(f2)
}
```

Comment: convenience I'd guess...

Comment: To imagine some of the other consequences of what you're proposing for how the language would look, recall structs can have multiple fields and allow field names for initializers, so if we used parens instead of braces `s(a,b,c)` could be a struct initializer that visually looks like a function call, and `s(field1: x, field2: y)` would be a literal too. So in addition to being grammatically necessary, it seems programmer-friendly that these different operations look different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyFloat(2)` is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). `MyFloat2{3}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Conversions can be used on structs:

```
 var f3 struct {
    X float64
 }
 f4 := MyFloat2(f3)
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/0Yjl18oaQg)